# Android keyEvent keycode for the "Xbox Button"

Tags: android, joystick, xbox

I am writing an app that uses a bluetooth connected Xbox controller, I can read all of the keyEvents fine via dispatchkeyevent EXCEPT the "Xbox Home" button (the one with the light in it), it just exits my app. Does anyone know if there's a keycode for this button?

Comment: Might it  be tied to the home button?  Which is probably grabbed by the system and never makes the app.

Comment: It might, however, the B button use to exit the app as well until I handled that particular keyEvent within the app so I figured it might be the same thing.